# How can I pick images ONLY from gallery/camera?

Tags: android, image

I use this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

But it shows all pictures which I have on phone, from other then gallery/camera files too. How could I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You need to

```
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media;

.
.
int IMAGE_PICKER_SELECT = 0;
.
.


Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, IMAGE_PICKER_SELECT);


/**
 * After photo is selecte, you can do the processing.
 */
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICKER_SELECT  && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
       // some code
    }
}
```

Comment: I get EXTERAL_CONTENT_URI cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Comment: try importing import android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media; and refer code mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

use this code to pick images from the gallery/camera only

```
pick = 0;
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, pick);
```

This should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I saw it but in my app I get error that EXTERAL_CONTENT_URI cannot be resolved or is not a field. Could you help me what can be wrong?

Comment: i've  never seen this problem before,try checking your imports,your manifest permissions and build your project again.